# Unholy table layout CSS: Possible to override TD placement in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So, before this starts a flame war, I realize that this is ridiculously bad form. However, I'm stuck within web software that can only output table layouts (I know, I know) and I want to override that behavior.

Basically, I have a single-row table with two cells, and I want to break the layout so that the second cell displays below the first one (instead of next to it). For modern browsers, there was an easy fix: set the `<td>` to `display:inline-block`. Problem solved. However, this (nor anything I've tried) does not work for IE8. IE8 stubbornly refuses to move that right cell below the left cell. And unfortunately, it seems I have to support IE8.

Anyone know of a way to make this terrible hack work?

Comment: I needed to do this in IE9 (in a Media Query), spent hours and days and nope, impossible. Even with `tbody { display: block }` necessary elsewhere even without having a tbody element. I guess it's the same for IE8 after testing `* {display: block !important }`

Comment: Thanks @FilipeAls. I decided to just hide the offending `<td>` with CSS in a conditional comment targeting less than IE 8.

Comment: If the information in it isn't necessary, why not. If it is, you could set the width of each cell to 50% in lesser IEs so it doesn't break. Or have an horizontal scrollbar. Won't look like modern browsers but you already have too much constraints (table layout being the first one and IE8 the second one ^^)